# How to upload files to firebase using HTTPClient Module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I started learning Angular by developing an simple shopping site clone web app, using firebase as a backend. I have used HTTP requests (get/post/put) to retrieve and modify data in the firebase.

Is there any way to upload images to the firebase storage using HTTP requests? If so, please help in these!

Answer (score 0):

```
fileUploader() {
    const file = ... // assign the image file here
    ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded the file!');
    });
}
```

Yes you use the above method to store the files to the cloud storage.

Comment: I am using rest api provided by firebase to connect Realtime database using http requests like these this.httpClient.put('REST API URL'+rowId+'.json', userData). So is there any way to upload image to firebase using this type of method?

Comment: You cant store files in real time database. you need to use firebase cloud storage